# Extract table to Google Sheets from HTTPresponse class containing html table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, httpresponse

In need of scraping html table to make use of it in Sheets I would normally use

```
=ImportHtml(URL, "table", num)
```

sheets formula. However, as long as I have to use logon to get data from page, there's plenty of advice  to make custom function to connect and retrieve the page using UrlFetchApp.fetch() method:

```
function retrieve() {
  var options = {};
  options.headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("User" + ":" + "passwd")};
  var connection = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://some.net/path", options);
  return connection.getContentText();
}
```

So I got page, that's fine. But as data, specifically HTTPresponse class. So as long as ImportHtml formula only takes as argument url address (in form of string) it can't simply consume just like that:

```
=ImportHtml(retrieve(), "table", 1)
```

What is the most convenient way to make table from resulting response? Is it possible to filter the result perhaps with ImportXml?

Answer (score 2):

In order to log in, you have to use Apps Script. But Apps Script cannot use spreadsheet functions like importXML. Instead, it offers [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service) which simplifies parsing HTML when it happens to be valid XML.

Often, the entire HTML document will fail to be parsed as XML, so it's best to cut out the part you actually need, such as a table. The self-contained sample below parses the 4th table on the Wikipedia page on Demographics of India:

```
function parseTable() {
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India").getContentText();
  var tableNumber = 4; 
  var table = "<table" + html.split("<table")[tableNumber].split("</table>")[0] + "</table>";
  var doc = XmlService.parse(table);
  var rows = doc.getDescendants().filter(function(c) {
    var element = c.asElement();
    return element && element.getName() == "tr";
  });
  var headers = rows[0].getChildren("th").map(function(cell) {
    return cell.getValue();
  });
  var data = rows.slice(1).map(function(row) {
    return row.getChildren("td").map(function(cell) {
      return cell.getValue();
    });
  });
  Logger.log(headers);
  Logger.log(data);    
}
```

What this does:

1. Parses the table into `doc`, an  XML document
2. Gets all elements with name "tr"
3. Extracts the contents of "th" children of the first row (assumed to be header row). If you don't care about the header row, skip this.
4. Extracts the contents of "td" children of other rows.
5. The output consists of 1D array `headers` and 2D array `data`

Note: tags are assumed to be lowercase here, as they usually are.

Comment: Thak you very much, Michelle! `GetContentText()` method should return string, however, line `var table = "<table" + html.split("<table")[tableNumber].split("</table>")[0] + "</table>";`
returns typeError as it won't let me `.split()` the _table_. Error message implies that the _table_ type is _undefined_.

Comment: I again copy-pasted this function in my script editor and it worked as intended. If you are parsing a different page, the reason would be with that page. If  `html.split("<table")[tableNumber]` is undefined, that would be because your page does not contain as many tables as you expect. Often, what appears to be a table is implemented as a bunch of `div` elements instead of an actual `table` element. Any necessary modifications for your specific use case are up to you; I did my part of showing how this can be done, with a working example.